# Convert Cognos 7 report to Cognos 8

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

We have a couple hundred legacy Cognos 7 reports that we need to convert to Cognos 8. I've been told from a couple sources that this has to be done manually, but I find that hard to believe. Surely at least part of the process can be automated. Does anyone know of any tools available that can assist in converting from Cognos 7 Impromptu to Cognos 8? Or does anyone with Cognos development experience know how to access the data from a Cognos 7 report and dump it into a table/XML file? I've been trying to parse the binary, and I'm getting some information like what data fields are included, which catalog it's using, etc. But if a map already exists, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognos provides migration tools for this.

[clicky!](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27015117#downloads)

It's been a really really really long time since I've done this, but that ought to get you going.